# How does the OR gate work?

Tags: multiplexer, logic-gates

[image]I'm asking this in reference to multiplexers where there are multiple inputs to the final OR gate. Say I have two different signals to an OR gate. One is at 4V and the other at 5V. So if I'm letting both them signals pass at the same time what should be the reading of OR gates' output? Will it be 4.5V or simple 5V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3x6OK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your OR gate were something as crude as Figure 1 the output voltage would be the average of the input voltages. This *might* be good enough for an application that just needed to know if either input was greater than zero volts but it's not good for logic circuits.

Figure 2 shows a better OR gate in that either input going high will provide current to the output. The problem is that there's a voltage drop because of the diode and if we were to propagate this signal through several stages the voltage drops would add up making the signal unusable. While not advised for proper logic circuits this can be a handy trick where an OR gate is required in a circuit that doesn't suit logic level chips or where, for some reason, the designer can't fit in a full 4-gate chip.

Figure 3 shows a logic chip OR gate. Internally some transistors are used to detect the input signals and, if they exceed a certain threshold voltage the output transistor is switched. This has the advantage that the output can now switch rail-to-rail and that the drive signal has no (or manageable) voltage drop. Each logic family has a 'fan-out' capability that tells you how many inputs an output can drive reliably.

[image]

*Figure 4. CMOS OR gate.*

Consider how the CMOS OR gate of figure 4 works.

- If A and B are both low Q1 and 2 will be off (open-circuit) and Q3 and 4 will be on (short circuit). Notice the 'o' invertor symbol on the gates of Q3, 4 and 5. Point 'C' will be pulled high to Vdd. This will turn off Q5 and turn on Q6 giving a low resistance path between Q and Vss.
- If either A OR B turns on one of the Q3 / Q4 transistors will turn off while one of the Q1 / Q2 transistor turn on pulling 'C' low. This will turn on Q5 and turn off Q6 giving a low-resistance path from Vdd to Q.

The point is that the output is '*driven*' high and '*driven*' low resulting in clean switching and the ability to provide enough current to reliably switch any downstream devices.

Comment: This means that whatever is the input in a logic chip OR gate the same appears on output? Considering data is being transmitted through them.

Comment: Yes, that way of thinking works for the OR gate but doesn't help you much with inverters, AND, NAND or XOR. Inside the OR gate the signal gets inverted twice. See my update.

Comment: The OR gate as a whole is then just transmitting Vdd and not the A's or B's signal isn't it?

Comment: Correct. Any logic gate will perform the logic and switch the output to V+ or GND giving a strong signal originating from the power supply rather than from the input.

Comment: So in a 4:1 MUX are the 4 signals acting as Vdd?

Comment: I've no idea. What does the datasheet say? Remember that you haven't provided a part number and link to a datasheet. Add these to your question so that everyone can see them and not in the comments.

Comment: By the 4 signals I meant the X1, X0, X2 and X3 in the diagram I posted. Do these act as Vdd's for the OR gate depending on what signal is being transmitted?

Answer (score 1):

Provided the inputs to a gate are at valid [logic levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_level), the output will go to the level it can, depending on load current, independently of the input levels.

In your case, *if* the output were unloaded, it will approach the positive power rail. Different logic families and devices have widely differing drive capabilities.

Without a part number to identify even the family (I can see it is a 5V part, and that is about it), I cannot be more definitive.

Answer (score 1):

It will show output as 5 V because it takes both 5V and 4.7V as high potential. The gate circuits have defined range of lower potential( e.g. 
0-2.2V) and high potential (e.g. 3- 5V) to give inputs and outputs in digital format .

Answer (score 0):

While the answers you've gotten are all correct, the key message you should be getting is that the answer to your question does not matter.

An OR gate has a defined minimum input high voltage (usually just called Vih(min)). Any voltage above this value is considered a logical high. If Vih(min) is 4 V, it doesn't matter if the input voltage is 4.5 or 5 or 4.0001 V, they're all considered logical high values.

And an OR gate has a defined minimum output high voltage (usually just called Voh(min)). If at least one of the input voltages is high, and you are using the part correctly (not overloading the output, not using an inadequate power supply, etc.) then the output voltage will be above Voh(min). How much above? It doesn't matter, because Voh(min) is always greater than Vih(min) for gates in a given logic family so the output value of the OR gate doesn't matter, because it will be above Vih(min) for the gate that's connected to its output.

As other answers have noted, a CMOS logic gate will tend to pull the output very near Vdd when outputting a high voltage if the load is very light (high impedance). I think nobody has mentioned yet that a 5 V TTL gate will actually not pull its output particularly close to Vcc (maybe around 3.5 V, IIRC), unless the load is really miniscule (greater than 1 megohm, maybe). But this is okay because the Vih(min) for TTL is very low, maybe 1.5 or 2 V (check your datasheet for the actual number).

Comment: Then how are OR gates used for data transmission? What I can't understand is since a MUX relays one of the many signals entering it and if an OR gate is being used in it shouldn't all signals, no matter which gate I enable, appear as high? How does the MUX become useful then?